# How to read in chunks of a file via chrome app?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I've got a reasonably small file (~50kB), that I'd like to manipulate in a chrome app at the byte level.

`chrome.storage.local` was my previous approach.  This has a quota of ~5MB, which is plenty for this application, but the documentation made it seem like this should really be more for managing user settings, etc.

`chrome.filesystem` seems to be more for allowing the user to select a file.  I'm reading through it now, but wanted to see if there's any guidance before I sink too much into one approach.

I would prefer to not have to store the file in a google drive account (this would be a dropbox or s3 link most likely).

Comment: Of note: you can remove local quota restrictions by specifying `unlimitedStorage` permission.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

Comment: You might want to eliminate the part of your question referring to downloading. You seem to be asking how to store a large file using a Chrome App, and that question can be answered without introducing the complication of downloading or any network activity. For example, you could write a 500MB file of zeroes to the HTML5 filesystem and then read that in chunks.

Comment: @sowbug, agreed.  simplifying question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. As the file is very small (you say around 50KB), you could just read it into your app and deal with it there. There are APIs for reading in a blob and then converting that to a byte array. A little web searching will get you to the APIs you need and most likely even examples
2. I wouldn't really bother doing this with only 50KB, but once you have a blob, you can access slices of it. There are APIs for getting slices, too. While it isn't documented anywhere that I have seen, if you do this, the actual physical reading of the blob seems to be delayed, so taking a slice really does read only the part you want.

Sorry I'm not more specific about the APIs, but it's late at night here and I don't have time to get to my normal reference sites. However, as I said, both of the above are fairly conventional techniques and you'll find tons of stuff on them on the web. Much of it is in Stackoverflow, by the way.

Comment: Fair enough, I should search more.  Thanks @MarcRochkind